# Controller testing fails due to the service dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

When making use of a service in a controller test do you need to initialize the service in the same way you would the controller? By this I mean do you need to pass it its own dependencies?

For example I can initialize my controller like so:

```
   // Instantiate the controller
    searchController = $controller( 'VisibilitySearchController',{
        $scope: scope,
        dataService: dataService
    });
}));
```

so do I need to initialize the service according to the components it needs like `$http`, `$resource` etc as well as make `spyOn` calls on its functions? Or is this/should this be sufficient? (Note - my tests fail when I do the following )

```
 // Instantiate the dataService
    dataService = $injector.get( 'dataService' );
```

it throws this error:

```
* Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- dataService
```

The relevant part of the service:

```
myAppServices.factory('dataService', ['$http', '$resource', 'authService', 'messageService', function ($http, $resource, authService, messageService) { 

 }
```

**Side note**

Note - we are using Maven as our build tool and only make use of Jasmine at this point - trying to bring Karma in as our test-runner as a Maven plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide all the dependencies but you can mock them. This can be done by jasmine like this for example:

```
var mockedDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj('dataService', ['getData', 'getOtherData']);
```

And then you inject this mocked service to `$provider`:

```
beforeEach(function () {
        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('dataService', mockedDataService );
        });
}
```

Instance of this mocked service can be retrieved like this then:

```
inject(function (dataService) {
    var dataServiceInstance = dataService;
});
```

This will provider mocked dataService anytime it is needed. However if you need fully functional dataService you must instantiate it but always you can mock any of its dependecies.

Comment: Based on what you said in the first sentence that would mean that when you test a controller you must provide it with all the dependencies instead of just the one  you want to test with - correct?

Comment: Yes, with all the dependencies. Without them, the engine won't be able to instantiate the controller. However you can mock the dependencies (provide faked ones) if you don't need or want the real functionality of them

Comment: thanks for the reply - can i stack the modules above for multiple services? Also - when you use the createSpyObj do you need to provide only the methods you use or all the methods defined? Thanks!

Comment: You can define it once and use it multiple times for any object needes it. You must define all methods which will be called otherwise it will fail. But you dont have to use spy, you can just create a dummy object yourself with whatever implementation you want for the test. You only have to use $provide to pass in the dummy object. Spies are great if you want to assert that a method was called and so on. If you dont need it you can skip spies

Answer (score 1):

While you **can** inject dependencies into the controller manually you don't need to do it as long as you have loaded the module the service belongs to.

In your case it looks like you have not loaded the `ngResource` module.

If you add `beforeEach(module('ngResource'))` to your test (and make sure the actual script file it lives in is included in Jasmine's fileset) you should not need to inject it manually.

Note that you do not need to load angular core services like `$http`, but since `$resource` is not part of core it needs to be loaded like this.

Injecting dependencies manually is mostly useful if you want to provide a mock implementation.